How to map returned std::map to Python dictionary using SWIG?
Mapping a Python dictionary argument to a C++ std::map is described in How does SWIG wrap a map<string,string> in Python? and works like a charm. As peastman's comment suggests I do not even need to explicitely call the map-string-string constructor.
Now I want to return a map:
std::map<std::string, std::string> const& getMetaData() const;

The return type is mapped to
<rawdata.map_string_string; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'std::map< std::string,std::string >

i.e. a C++ map object wrapped by SWIG. I can access it using operator[], size(), keys() etc. but what I really want is a native Python dictionary. Can SWIG do this or do I need to write a custom typemap that copies all the key / value pairs?

As far as I know, SWIG does not include such a typemap, you will have to write it yourself. I did write it for JavaScript in SWIG JSE - so you can use this as an inspiration: https://github.com/mmomtchev/swig/blob/5efd3f544a7d1018c9e445e95b226f38b20e2e1d/Lib/javascript/napi/std_map.i#L166
You will have to replace the Node.js Node-API with Python C-API

If you've written a suitable %template then SWIG provides a swig::from() method to convert to a Python dict. But yes, it copies all the key/value pairs. I think that's inevitable as Python dicts are not implemented as C++ maps.
